# How to implements a custom view compatible with AutoLayout that has dynamic height?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to implements a customize, and the view's height can be calculated according to it's content and *width*. The view's width is arbitrary and in IB usually set leading and trailing offset. The question is how can I get the width of this view and do the layout?
A similar view is UILabel, if set `numberOfLines` property to 0 it can adjust it's height according to content and width. UILabel has a property `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, during constraints update, this property is set to correct width and using these do the work. And the same, when and how this property is set?

For example, i have a grid image which look like this
[image]

If width is given, then we can calculate the height of the view. And I have pin it to a cell like this
[image]

So the cell's height will adjust according by the grid image view's height.
But how did i know the exact width of the grid image view? The actually result is following when the table view first shown.
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you're having and what you want to have as it's not entirely clear?

Comment: AFAIK, the size of a view can be determined by its subviews. Just add proper constraints and it will be pretty easy to achieve your goal.